# BootsrapValidator doesn't work with Backbone View

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a form to change password

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="passwordForm" role="form">

        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "passworActuel" class = "col-sm-1 control-label" >Password actuel</label>
            <div class = "col-sm-3">
                <input type = "password" id = "passwordActuel" name = "passwordActuel" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Password actuel"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">
            <div class = 'col-sm-offset-1'>
                <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default" >Enregistrer</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

And I have my Backbone View :

```
define([... , 'bootstrapValidator', ...],
function(..., bootstrapValidator, ...){

    var validator = function(){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#passwordForm').bootstrapValidator({
                fields:{
                    passwordActuel:{
                        validators:{
                            notEmpty:{
                                message : "Le champs du mot de passe actuel doit être renseigné"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    };

    var ChangePasswordView = Backbone.View.extend({

        render : function(){
            this.$el.html(ChangePasswordTemplate());
            validator();

            return this;
        }
    });

    return ChangePasswordView;
});
```

The form appear but my field isn't verified by bootsrapValidator. I haven't error on my consonle. I think maybe validator is loaded before the template.